# Why do I need to_url() method in path converter? Django

Tags: python, django, url

Why do I need the `to_url(self, value)` method in path converter for in Django?

I can find only few examples on official docs and can't understand the use of this method.

What does to_url() do exactly?

```
class FourDigitYearConverter:

    regex = '[0-9]{4}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return int(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return '%04d' % value
```

Comment: The reason you need this is explained further down in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Answer (score 5):

The `to_url(self, value)` method in a Django converter is employed during the URL reversing process, which involves generating a URL based on the view name and its associated parameters.

In the given example, suppose you have a view utilizing the converter as shown below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('my-view/<FourDigitYearConverter:year>/', MyView.as_view(), name='my_view'),
]
```

In this case, the to_url method will be invoked to create the URL when using the reverse method, like so:

```
url = reverse('my_view', kwargs={'year': year_value})
```

If you attempt to use the reverse method with a path that employs a converter lacking the to_url method definition, you will encounter an error similar to:

```
AttributeError: 'FourDigitYearConverter' object has no attribute 'to_url'
```

I hope this clarifies your question!

Answer (score 0):

This method converts a value for example in this case a number into a string that can be used in a URL for example if the value is an integer (e.g 4)  it will be formatted as '0004'.

Comment: It's supposed to build a url, isn't it? Could you provide me an example in real code?

Comment: You just repeated what [the documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters), this isn't a helpful answer for someone who doesn't understand why a URL converter needs to be able to perform the inverse operation and what (and where) this method is used for. I had this question after reading the documentation and needing more context.

Answer (score -1):

actually when you put any kind of url like this in the url `{% url 'post' post.id %}` at this time the argument in the `'post.id' first converted into the url format from python to url.`

Answer (score -1):

As of what I know, to_url() converts the integers that are needed to be in between strings in an URL into strings. for example [www.fb.com/id=20,name=jondoe](http://www.fb.com/id=20,name=jondoe) into /id=20%name=jon+doe

Comment: Which integers are you talking about? Why should `id=20,name=jondoe` be converted to `id=20%name=jon+doe`  - how would the converter know that `jondoe`  should be converted to `jon+doe`?

Comment: I meant jon doe, with a space in between.